# How to Handle 'iron-ajax` Timeout

Tags: ajax, polymer, timeout

The `iron-ajax` web component has a timeout property, but after reading through the components code on GitHub I am not sure how to handle it.

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{response}}"
  method="get"
  timeout="5000"
  url="https://api.domain.com/">
</iron-ajax>
```

Does it fire an event?

Is it observable?

How can I run a function when a request reaches its timeout limit?

Comment: Define "timeout limit"? Polymer will send an event when last response changes event name is "last-response-changed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout property on `iron-ajax` is the number of milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated. As this timeout is an error the `iron-ajax` element will fire an `error` event which you can use to call a function when triggered. For instance:

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{response}}"
  method="get"
  timeout="5000"
  url="https://api.domain.com/"
  on-error="_showError">
</iron-ajax>
```

...

```
class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-ele'; }

  ...

  _showError(event, request) {
    // display error message
  }
}
```